# java spring jpa nothing saved in DB table when using entityManager.clear()

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

I'm building a trading application. The application iterates over 1400 stock, and for each stock, prices are read from the DB. After reading the prices, I do an entityManager.clear() so that the persistence context is emptied. Without clear(), the system becomes extremely slow.
I create new java objects (**DatePrice**) from the entities (**InstrumentPrice**) which are read from the DB

Then, calculations are performed on the list of DatePrice objects, and these calculations are then stored in another DB table.  But Nothing is saved in this DB table.

When I remove entityManager.clear() , then the calculations are saved in the table, but the application becomes unacceptable slow.

Why does the entityManager.clear() affects a new Transaction ?

```
public void performCalculation(TaRequestDto taRequestDto, Stock stock) throws Exception {

            List<InstrumentPrice> instrumentPriceList = instrumentPriceDao.getPricesBetweenDates(stock, taRequestDto.getDateFrom(), taRequestDto.getDateTo());
            List<DatePrice> datePriceList = InstrumentPriceUtil.convertInstrumentPriceListToDatePriceList(instrumentPriceList);

            calculationService.execute(datePriceList, stock);
 }
```

Class  InstrumentPriceDao

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public List<InstrumentPrice> getPricesBetweenDates(Stock stock, LocalDate dateFrom, LocalDate dateTo) {

    List<InstrumentPrice> instrumentPriceList;
    instrumentPriceList = getPriceForAllStocksBetweenDates(dateFrom, dateTo);

    entityManager.clear();
    return instrumentPriceList;
}
```

Class CalculationService

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void execute(List<DatePrice> datePriceList, Stock stock) throws Exception {

            // do some calculations
            List(Double) calculatedValues = ........

            calculationDao.insertCalculations(stock, calculatedValues);
}
```

Class  calculationDao

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public calculation insertCalculations(Stock stock, List<Double> calculatedValues ) {

    Calculation = new Calculation();
    // setting properties ...

    return entityManager.persist(calculation);
}
```

Comment: You should post the code that makes the insertion. It may matter.

Answer (score 0):

So you do a clear, that means you remove all your entities from your persistence context. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear--

"Clear the persistence context, causing all managed entities to become detached. **Changes made to entities that have not been flushed to the database will not be persisted**."

Do a flush before, this writes your changes to your database:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush--

"Synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database."

```
entityManager.flush();    
entityManager.clear();
```

Comment: Isn't JPA doing a commit when a method (annotated with Transaction)  finishes ?   And isn't that commit writing the DB ?

Comment: I added  entityManager.flush();   ,   but still nothing saved in the DB.

Comment: Also, the entities  InstrumentPrice  may be detached from the persistence context. These are not the objects which are saved in the DB.  It is the entity calculation which is saved in the DB (in a new Transaction)